# How is this happening with static?

Tags: c++

Need help to understand the following behaviour.

```
static int a;
int b[a];

for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    b[i] = i+1;

for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    cout << " " << b[i];
```

The output is 
$> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 8 10

However if I declare variable 'a' as auto [like int a] then it crashes at run-time, which is obvious. But why is it working with static.
Also if I run the loop for more number of time(above it is 10) it crashes. I made it 12 and it crashed. Moreover in the output 8 is coming instead of 9 in between 8 & 10 which is abnormal. Please help.....

Comment: This doesn't compile. Is this the whole code?

Comment: it isn't the problem, problem is with variables 'a'. It has default value ( equals 0 ).

Comment: Also using a [GCC extension](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html) for variable length arrays in C++ mode is not a great idea.

Answer (score 5):

Static variables without an explicit initializer are initialized to zero.

```
static int a;
int b[a];
```

`b` is initialized as an array of 0 `int`.

C++ doesn't do any boundary check, it lets you access the array outside its bounds, but it invokes undefined behavior.

---

`int b[a];` declares a variable length array and this is just an extension provided by your compiler, this is not part of the standard and therefore not portable.

As [@Als](https://stackoverflow.com/users/452307/als) suggests, you could compile with the `-pedantic` compiler option which would throw something like

> ISO C++ forbids variable-size array

---

What you seem to want is just

```
static int b[10];
```

Comment: b is not initialized, int b[0] is illegal.

Comment: @Luchian Grigore, I suppose that was just a missing semicolon.

Comment: No, you just can't define arrays of 0 length.

Comment: Guys, that's what is my query......that although b is an array of size 0 how the assignments b[i] = i+1; [i=0 to 10] are working?

Comment: In GCC, you can do both: Have variable sized arrays, and have zero-sized arrays. Unless you place "ansi" compiler flag, it works.

Comment: It working because you can have in this piece memory some trash. Array in c++ doesn't throw exception when you get out of range. But when your program write on protect memory, it crashes

Comment: @Luchian, `a` is not a constant expression, I suppose the OP is using g++, which has an extension for VLAs.

Comment: @Bertrand Marron: I think you shuold also update your answer, to tell that `VLA` are not supported by the C++ standard, it is just a gcc compiler extension which supports their usage & such code will be non portable. compiling with `-pedantic` will point out the same.

Comment: C doesn't check bounds of an array.

Comment: @Rudy Velthuis, who said it did?

Comment: My reply was to a comment by paper plane. I answered when I only saw a few comments, and I had missed the comments that were hidden. Paper plane wrote `although b is an array of size 0 how the assignments b[i] = i+1; [i=0 to 10] are working?` and that was my answer: C doesn't check array bounds.

Answer (score 2):

```
static int a;
```

means `a` is initialized to zero so the following line:

`int b[a];`

makes no sense.

You getting output is completely kind of strange because
i'm getting compilation error;

`error: array bound is not an integer constant`

In C++(at least) the variable `a` has to be `const`.

Answer (score 1):

The size of array `b[]` is not known, and I don't see that you have assigned any value to `a` ,
what you are seeing is **undefined behavior**.

Assuming `a` is not global, When made `static`, it will not be on the stack, instead, it may be placed in the data section

Answer (score 0):

It crashes because you don't initialize variables a (default initialized for static int is 0). Write example:

```
 static int a = 50;
```

and it will be working fine

## edit

It working sometimes because you have luckily and in this piece of memory are some trash. Array in c++ doesn't throw exception when you get out of range. But when your program write on protect memory, it will crash

Comment: There is no default value for `int`. It is zero-initialized because it is `static`, if it would be default initialized the value would be indeterminate.

Comment: I didn't say that 0 is default value for int. It is default value in this example (for static variables)

Comment: The misunderstanding here is probably over the term "default value". That's close to the formal term "default initialized", but "default value" is not a formal term in this context.

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of an initializer, static variables are guaranteed to be initialized to zero.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you were simply lucky that it doesn't crash. `a` is initialised to 0, and that means you are writing to memory past the array and that can mean anything.

**I assume you were expecting a crash**. Fact is that even if you access memory beyond an array limit, that doesn't automatically mean you get a crash. It can also overwrite other variables or memory contents of your code. This can go noticed (e.g. with a crash), or it can be silent, producing weird results.

It is not called "undefined" behaviour for nothing.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems here.

First and foremost: this is invalid C++.  It looks like you're using C99's variable-length arrays, which never made it into any C++ standard.  I'm surprised your compiler isn't at least warning you.  In C++, array lengths **must** be a compile-time constant.

You never initialize `a`.  When `a` is made static it gets initialized by default to `0`, so you are creating a zero-length array.  When it's not static, no such implicit initialization is done -- it has an undefined value.  Thus the array is created with an undefined length, and it's quite possible it's too large to fit in your stack space and is causing the crash.

Additionally, in the `static` variant you're reading/writing 10 elements in a 0-length array, which also results in undefined behavior.  This means the standard doesn't define what happens in this weird case, and so *anything* is allowed to happen.  It is only working for you purely by chance!

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing array out-of-bounds, which would simlpy cause buffer-overrun. The program may or may not run, and hence the term "undefined behavoir"